# in testNG selenium, when adding new class in xml file test case flow is not working as expected

Tags: selenium, testing, junit, automation, testng

I am exploring selenium with testNG.

I wrote 6-7 test classes in which i am running from project.xml file, and it is working fine but when ever i add a new specified test class all the testing flow changes and behaving weird, when ever i remove that class from .xml file it is working as expected.

Even that class is working when i try to run alone using .xml file.

```
The flow is like
class 1 --> test 1
class 2 --> test 1
class 3 --> test 1
class 4 --> test 1
now it continues like this
class 1 --> test 2
class 2 --> test 2
class 3 --> test 2
class 4 --> test 2
and continues....
```

This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Candidate" parallel="false">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <test name="Chrome test" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageName.class1" />
            <class name="packageName.class2" />
            <class name="packageName.class3" />
            <class name="packageName.class4" />
            <class name="packageName.class5" />
            <class name="packageName.class6" />
            <class name="packageName.ProblemWithThisClass" />

        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Did i do any wrong with code? or is any configuration i missed to configure for .xml file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share the code..

Answer (score 0):

If u mean you need to preserve the order , do like this

```
<suite name="Preserve order test runs">
   <test name="Regression 1" preserve-order="true">
     <classes>
       <class name="com.pack.preserve.ClassOne"/>
       <class name="com.pack.preserve.ClassTwo"/>
       <class name="com.pack.preserve.ClassThree"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

By using preserve-order="true" , it will make sure that the testNG will run the Test classes in same sequence

Comment: even after adding  preserve-order="true", its behaving same

Comment: Here is a complete example how to preserve order, if still it is not working for you, then share the code in that case